# Reconstructing sms.db

Tags: ios, sqlite

#### Backstory

This afternoon, I replied to a text from my girlfriend, then apparently neglected to sleep my phone before putting it back in my pocket. When I pulled it back out a few minutes later, my phone had decided to hit "Edit->Clear All" on the conversation, vaporizing two years and two phones worth of SMS history with her. While I have a backup of the phone, it's close to three weeks old at this point, and there's enough solid discussion that I'd like to reconstruct; I've already grabbed a copy of sms.db, but I think the method I used vacuumed the file, so there are no soft-deleted texts in it.

### Meat of the Question

I have a three-week old backup of *my* `sms.db`, and have access to date copy of *her* `sms.db`. I'd like to

1. export the texts she has but I don't (easy, at least to CSV)
2. change the "perspective" info (the `address` field and the `sent/received/deleted/unknown` field), keeping the timestamp and text
3. import/merge these new entries into *my* old `sms.db` backup
4. merge this updated backup with my current `sms.db` (optional/there seems to be an online utility for that)

I don't really know SQL but would be willing to learn; the problem I have is that from what I understand, the tables within `sms.db` have become more interdependent over the OS's lifespan, and the triggers now call C functions that don't exist outside the phone, so it's not a simple matter of calling a single trigger on multiple entries. Does anyone know of any ways to work around this complexity, or even better, any utilities that have already figured out how to import individual entries into `sms.db`?

#### Edit:

I've been examining `sms.db`, and from what I can tell, the relationships are pretty straightforward:

- for `message`, I need to mostly make sure that the ROWID of any added messages are higher than the current highest ROWID
- `msg_group` holds the `message:ROWID` of the last message for each contact; I can lookup the correct `address` within `group_member`; `group_member:group_id` corresponds with `msg_group:ROWID`
- **`msg_group` has a hash column; this will probably be the hardest thing to update, since I'm not immediately sure what it's updating, or what hash to use**
- `sqlite_sequence`doesn't seem like it's quite up-to-date; its entries seem to all be smaller than the actual ROWIDs, but I assume this means I won't have to mess with it very much.
- I'm not really sure that I'll be able to change `msg_pieces` at all: it's the table in charge of handling the multiple parts of an MMS message.

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you get this sorted out? if you haven't I suggest taking a look at http://smsmerge.homedns.org/

I have been in a similar position as you have, but I was lucky and had a more recent backup than that.

Let me know if you need a hand with it

Comment: I have seen that, thanks! I'll definitely be using it to stitch the two tables back together, but I never did get around to taking her side of the conversation around so it looks like my phone's version of events. I need to work on that...